# Search and write line of a very large file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I have a big `csv` file containing 60210 lines. Those lines contains hashes, paths and file names, like so:

```
hash                 | path     | number | hash-2      | name 
459asde2c6a221f6...  | folder/..| 6      | 1a484efd6.. | file.txt
777abeef659a481f...  | folder/..| 1      | 00ab89e6f.. | anotherfile.txt
....
```

I am filtering this file regarding a list of hashes, and to the facilitate the filtering process, I create and use a reduced version of this file, like so:

```
hash                 | path     
459asde2c6a221f6...  | folder/..
777abeef659a481f...  | folder/..
```

The filtered result contains all the lines that have a hash which is not present in my reference hash base.

But to make a correct analysis of the filtered result, I need the previous data that I removed. So my idea was to read the filtered result file, search for the `hash` field, and write it in an enhanced result file that will contain all the data.

I use a loop to do so:

```
getRealNames() {
    originalcontent="$( cat $originalfile)"
    while IFS='' read -r line; do
        hash=$( echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d " " )
        originalline=$( echo "$originalcontent"  |grep "$hash" )
        if [ ! -z "$originalline" ]; then
            echo "$originalline" > "$resultenhanced"
        fi
    done < "$resultfile"
}
```

But in real usage, it is highly inefficient: for the previous file, this loop takes approximately 3 hours to run on a 4Go RAM, Intel Centrino 2 system, and it seems to me way too long for this kind of operation.

Is there any way I can improve this operation?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what is your exact output for your given input. Update the question with the exact details

Comment: @Inian just did it. I am basically filtering the lines regarding a reference hash base, and I want to get the list of all hashes that are not in this reference base.

Comment: Could you give more lines of input for test. For now all lines in ref are in the original file

Comment: 60K lines isn't that big; why bother reducing it?

Comment: It is a requirement of the filter function I am using. I have to format the input that way in order to filter correctly.

Comment: That's not a "very large file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the nature of your question, it is hard to understand why you would prefer using the shell to process such a huge file given specialized tools like `awk` or `sed` to process them. As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) points out in the wonderful answer in [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/112235).

Your problem becomes easy to solve once you use `awk`/`perl` which speeds up the text processing. Also you are consuming the whole file into RAM by doing `originalcontent="$( cat $originalfile)"` which is not desirable at all.

Assuming in the both the original and reference file, the `hash` starts at the first column and the columns are separated by `|`, you need to use `awk` as

```
awk -v FS="|" 'FNR==NR{ uniqueHash[$1]; next }!($1 in uniqueHash)' ref_file orig_file
```

The above attempts takes into memory only the first column entries from your reference file, the original file is not consumed at all. Once we consume the entries in `$1` (first column) of the reference file, we do filter on the original file by selecting those lines that are not in the array(`uniqueHash`) we created.

Change your `locale` settings to make it even faster by setting the `C` locale as `LC_ALL=C awk ...`

Comment: I don't really know about `awk` but it seems to be a perfectly great solution to my issue. I will search a little bit more about those tools and come back to you.

Answer (score -2):

Your explanation of what you are trying to do unclear because it describes two tasks: filtering data and then adding missing values back to the filtered data. Your sample script addresses the second, so I'll assume that's the what you are trying to solve here.

As I read it, you have a filtered result that contains hashes and paths, and you need to lookup those hashes in the original file to get the other field values. Rather than loading the original file into memory, just let *grep* process the file directly. Assuming a single space (as indicated by `cut -d " "`) is your field separator, you can extract the hash in your *read* command, too.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r hash data; do
    grep "$hash" "$originalfile" >> "$resultenhanced"
done < "$resultfile"
```

Comment: Repeatedly running `grep` on a large file is an awful antipattern.